# Stretch UILabel background dynamically.

Tags: iphone, uilabel

I'm trying to recreate this UITableView cell design.

[image]

This is as far as I have got...

[image]

I'm looking for a way of stretching the background of my UILabel dynamically. It needs to stretch at a specific point in the middle of my background.png image.

Does something like this exist? Am I going about solving this problem the right way?

I'm very new to iPhone dev so please be gentle.

Answer (score 1):

Well there are many solutions, first you can set the image as a background color.
This is what you have done already by the looks of it, but you need to make the image repeatable.

Meaning it can't really have a start or an end.

Another way is to add an `UIImageView` behind the `UILabel` and set the image to a stretchable with a left and top cap. 
This wil stretch the image but will leave the top/bottom and beginning/end the way they are.

You can read more about this in the Apple doc: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html